# Spring JPA. Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'roles_ibfk_1' are incompatible

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa

Мне нужно создать связь «один к одному», но у меня возникает данная ошибка при сборке программы (BUILD FAILURE).

Есть две модели, где Role имеет ссылку на User.

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public User() {}

    public User(Long id, String username, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User userId;

    @Column(name = "role_name", nullable = false)
    private String roleName;

    public Role() {}

    public Role(Long id, User userId, String roleName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

И вот сама ошибка

```
2024-01-09T13:34:19.776+03:00  WARN 3200 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table roles modify column user_id bigint" via JDBC [Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'roles_ibfk_1' are incompatible.]

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table roles modify column user_id bigint" via JDBC [Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'roles_ibfk_1' are incompatible.]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:574) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:514) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.migrateTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:333) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:232) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:315) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1232) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at arkadisahakyan.authenticationwithspring.AuthenticationWithSpringApplication.main(AuthenticationWithSpringApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'roles_ibfk_1' are incompatible.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    ... 38 common frames omitted

Hibernate: alter table users modify column id bigint not null
2024-01-09T13:34:19.792+03:00  WARN 3200 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table users modify column id bigint not null" via JDBC [Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'roles_ibfk_1' are incompatible.]

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table users modify column id bigint not null" via JDBC [Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'roles_ibfk_1' are incompatible.]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:574) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:514) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.migrateTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:333) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:232) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:315) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1232) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at arkadisahakyan.authenticationwithspring.AuthenticationWithSpringApplication.main(AuthenticationWithSpringApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'roles_ibfk_1' are incompatible.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    ... 38 common frames omitted

2024-01-09T13:34:19.823+03:00  INFO 3200 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-01-09T13:34:20.714+03:00  WARN 3200 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-01-09T13:34:21.386+03:00  INFO 3200 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@725490dd, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@15ca7322, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@5b4880b3, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3ef7fb04, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@4c89c98a, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@61d9dd15, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@df04d12, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4bc39640, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1e37cb10, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@28200d43, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4779df3d, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@20cf3ab3]
2024-01-09T13:34:21.932+03:00  INFO 3200 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-01-09T13:34:21.948+03:00  INFO 3200 --- [           main] a.a.AuthenticationWithSpringApplication  : Started AuthenticationWithSpringApplication in 16.888 seconds (process running for 18.02)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  08:58 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-09T13:42:48+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.1:run (default-cli) on project authentication-with-spring: Process terminated with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Как правильно определить связь «один к одному» для Spring Data JPA?**

Вот так выглядит описание моих таблиц в СУБД

```
mysql> describe users;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| username | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| password | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> describe roles;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | bigint       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| user_id   | int          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| role_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Скорее всего у вас стоит `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`, и поэтому после изменения сущностей Hibernate пытается "обновить" базу при помощи `alter table` запросов.  Вероятно, в данном случае проще было бы пересоздать базу с нуля, использовав `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

Comment: Безотносительно к указанной проблеме, не совсем понятно, почему была выбрана связь one-to-one для пользователей и ролей (даже для учебного проекта), так как в реальном мире и некоторые пользователи могут иметь несколько ролей, и к заданной роли могут относиться несколько пользователей.

Comment: @NowhereMan действительно. Я убрал вовсе эту опцию и она запустилась. Вы могли бы пояснить в общих чертах что могло помешать исполнению программы с этой опцией? Да, возможно many-to-many было бы лучшим решением, но мне one-to-one показалась легче в применении, и поэтому я выбрал это.

Comment: Опция `update` полезна, когда к существующей объектной модели/базе добавляются какие-то сущности и следовательно создаются новые таблицы.  Если же рефакторится существующая база (меняются типы колонок, связи, ограничения (constraints)), то значительно возрастают шансы на проблемы с миграциями, особенно если они выполняются в автоматическом режиме.

Comment: @NowhereMan получается, что я как-то не так описал мои модели в программе, что Spring Data JPA не сумела понять как именно выглядит эта таблица и вследствие произошли эти ошибки?

Comment: Скорее всего вы просто сохраняли и запускали код несколько раз, если возникла такая рассинхронизация объектной модели и схемы базы данных.